# Find out dependencies of all DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assemblies

I have a collection of DLLs(say 20). How do I find out all the DLLs on which one specific DLL (say DLL A) is depending upon?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you mean programmatically, use [`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx).

You can use that recursively to find all the assemblies you need. (So you find the dependencies of X, then the dependencies of the dependencies, etc.)

Comment: you will need to include "using System.Reflection;"

Comment: @greenfeet: Not necessarily - you could use `var assemblies = typeof(Foo).Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();` for example. In general, it's not worth adding all the namespaces used by all the types referenced in answers - particularly not when there are links to the types in question. I kind of assume that readers understand enough of the C# language to know when to add a `using` directive.

Comment: Could you avoid adding `using System.Reflection` for the dependencies of the dependencies? Wouldn't you have to invoke Assembly.LoadWithPartialName (or something similar) at some point?

Comment: @theoski: Using directives just mean you don't have to fully-qualify names... I don't really see what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you meant something else when you said 'links to the types in question', when I should have known you were talking about the [Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) link. I thought maybe there was some way to avoid using statements in the C# (not that I would want to). I was just curious.

Comment: Accepted answer will only work for .NET libs and execs; mentioning because OP does not specify that they know the origin of the files to be inspected, only that it's a C# question.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: Given that it was accepted and no other information was provided, I think it's reasonable to assume it *is* about .NET assemblies.

Comment: I understand that might have been the intent, @JonSkeet, but as I ran across this question while looking for something less specific in regards to DLLs, the description of the question, its tags, and lack of mentioning assemblies vs. generalized DLLs can cause confusion. I'm not questioning the validity of your answer for the OP.

Answer (score 17):

Since the question is tagged "C#", I would assume you are talking about managed dlls (assemblies). In that case, dependencywalker is not useful. If you want to do that with a program, good ones are dotPeek by JetBrians and Reflector by RedGate. Or you can even use the object inspector in Visual Studio.

However, it can be a long process and cumbersome too. I would write a short C# program/F# script that uses `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`, as Jon mentioned.

If instead you want to examine native DLLs dependencies with a program (C# code), you have to walk the examine the PE file (the MS dll and exe file format) and its IAT (import address table). Not easy, but not impossible...

I would start [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) to understand PE sections, and use a managed library to read it (there are many, including some from the Mono project (I'm thinking of [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil), it should work with native binaries too); in the past I have used [this one](http://perwapi.codeplex.com/) from the good John Gough.

Answer (score 15):

All answer credit goes to previous authors for the usage of `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`. This is just a write-and-forget C# console app that works solely for .NET assemblies. `return 0` on assemblies you were able to check, and when successful, outputs them to STDOUT. Everything else will `return 1` and print some kind of error output. You can grab the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/02ef408011584f7e2b86f65f45e18e5a).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
namespace DotNetInspectorGadget
{
    class DotNetInspectorGadget 
    {
        static int Main(string[] args) 
        {
          if(args.GetLength(0) < 1)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Add a single parameter that is your" +
            " path to the file you want inspected.");
            return 1;
          }
          try {
                var assemblies = Assembly.LoadFile(@args[0]).GetReferencedAssemblies();

                if (assemblies.GetLength(0) > 0)
                {
                  foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
                  {
                    Console.WriteLine(assembly);
                  }
                  return 0;
                }
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return 1;
          } finally{}

            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
call %cd%\dotnet_inspector_gadget.exe C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.ConfigCI.Commands\v4.0_10.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.ConfigCI.Commands.dll
```

Output:

> ```
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
> System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
> System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
> System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
> System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
> System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
> System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
> ```

Answer (score 11):

You can use dependency walker http://www.dependencywalker.com to figure this out. Take note on the difference between x32 and x64 though.

> Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit
>   Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical
>   tree diagram of all dependent modules.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't support .net assemblies.

Answer (score 7):

For .NET assemblies, a terrific tool to view the assemblies an assembly is dependent on is [AsmSpy](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.nl/2011/02/asmspy-little-tool-to-help-fix-assembly.html).

Comment: It doesn't list indirect assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the DLL's (the files) then, `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` will also return the .Net Framework assemblies.

Here is a simple code snippet that will get the dll's it can find in the current directory (and also include some other related files):

```
private readonly string[] _extensions = { ".dll", ".exe", ".pdb", ".dll.config", ".exe.config" };

private string[] GetDependentFiles(Assembly assembly)
{
    AssemblyName[] asm = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
    List<string> paths = new List<string>(asm.Length);
    for (int t = asm.Length - 1; t >= 0; t--)
    {
        for (int e = _extensions.Length - 1; e >= 0; e--)
        {
            string path = Path.GetFullPath(asm[t].Name + _extensions[e]);
            if (File.Exists(path)) paths.Add(path);
        }
    }

    return paths.ToArray();
}
```

You can call it like so: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\r\n", GetDependentFiles(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())));`

Answer (score 0):

This example  shows a situation where we also want to display recursive dependencies. Tested with .net 4.5.2

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

var assemblyPath = @"C:\Temp\Some-Assembly.dll";
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
var indent = 0;
PrintDependencies(assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies(), ref indent, new List<string>());

private void PrintDependencies(
    IEnumerable<AssemblyName> names, 
    ref int indent, 
    ICollection<string> visited)
{
    indent++;
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        Print(name, indent);
        if (visited.Contains(name.FullName)) continue;
        visited.Add(name.FullName);
        var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(name.FullName);
        PrintDependencies(assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies(), ref indent, visited);
    }
    indent--;
}

// Rich text box was used, but can be anything else
private void Print(AssemblyName name, int indent) 
    => richTextBox.AppendText($"{new string('-', indent * 4)}{name.FullName}{Environment.NewLine}");
```

[image]