# How to avoid loading unnessecary assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

ASP.NET .NET 4.6 MVC4 application loads unnessecary assemblie, eq. System.Data.OracleClient . Oracle is not used.

Assembly dependencies are created using code in controller

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Assembly b in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            sb.AppendLine(b.FullName);
            foreach (AssemblyName an in b.GetReferencedAssemblies())
                sb.AppendLine("   " + an.Name);
        }
```

Output is below. According to this System.Web references to System.Design and System.Design references to System.Data.OracleClient

MVC Application is running in VPS server with limited memory. How to fix this so that unnessecary assemblies are not loaded? 
This will hopefully free some memory in VPS server.

```
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   mscorlib
   System.Drawing
   System
   System.Configuration
   System.Core
   System.Data
   System.Xml
   System.DirectoryServices
   System.EnterpriseServices
   System.Web.RegularExpressions
   System.Design
   System.Web.ApplicationServices
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols
   System.Security
   System.Runtime.Caching
   System.ServiceProcess
   System.Web.Services
   Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0
   Microsoft.Build.Framework
   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0
   System.Windows.Forms
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
   mscorlib
   System.Configuration
   System.Xml
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
   mscorlib
   System
   System.Xml
   System.Numerics
   System.Security
System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
   mscorlib
   System
   System.Configuration
System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   mscorlib
   System
   System.Xml
   System.Security
   System.Core
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
   mscorlib
   System
   System.Data.SqlXml
   System.Configuration
System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   mscorlib
   System
   System.Data
   System.Configuration
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   mscorlib
   Microsoft.Build.Framework
   System
   System.Xml
   System.Core
...
System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
   mscorlib
   System.Configuration
   System.Data
   System.Transactions
   System
   System.EnterpriseServices
```

web.config binding section does not also contain it:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**Update**

I tried according to answer to place remove command to web.config but got error

[image]

Also tried to remove oracle section according to answer using

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.data.oracleclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <remove name="system.data.oracleclient"></remove>
    </section>
  </configSections>
  ...
```

but got error:

[image]

How to fix it ?

Comment: right click on the reference on the project and click remove will do that, are you looking for some other option?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient is not referenced by any project is solution. However output in question shows that it is stll loaded.

Comment: does it have a reference on runtime assembly binding section on web.Config?

Comment: No. I updated question and added binding section. I searched solution for a word oracle and havent found any using statement or direct reference.

Comment: I needed a refresher on this topic myself, and found a very useful link: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded. From the article it seems that you are out of luck: ASP.NET will preload all references (even unused ones), whereas e.g. a simple Console app will not. If all this is true then you may just have to live with it.

Comment: ASP.NET does not have hard-coded data-provider references. `System.Data.OracleClient` should not referenced from System.Web, System.Design and similar assemblies. Why it is still loaded ? Maybe there is some hidden configuration which forces it to load dynamically ?

Comment: Check for instances of Oracle in your `machine.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three kind of assemblies on a web application.

1. assemblies that are come together with the libraries (dlls) that you use
2. assemblies that are the compiled version of your web application
3. assemblies that are main to run the site

### Libraries

In the first one case, you can optimize **yours libraries**, removing any unnecessary reference direct on the project of your dll.

### Reference

In the second case to optimize your web page and what to compile you need to remove any unnecessary reference on the code behind... eg page usually have this first lines

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

and what you do not use there are gray, you can remove it...

### web assemblies

And now the difficult part - difficult because you must play the "try/fail" game. Now what you can remove and from where.

First where to I search to find what to remove... and the answer is on global web.config on **asp.net**. In my case I go to **windows** directory, on my curent framework version, on **config** directory and find the `web.config`

There I locate some keys....

First you can remove **unnecessary Http Modules for faster pipeline** in the `httpModule`session on `web.config`

This is what I see on global web.config

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule" />
    <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
    <add name="WindowsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule" />
    <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <add name="PassportAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.PassportAuthenticationModule" />
    <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" />
    <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
    <add name="FileAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule" />
    <add name="AnonymousIdentification" type="System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule" />
    <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" />
    <add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    <add name="ScriptModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
```

and I go to web.config on my application and this is how I remove what I am not use:

```
<httpModules>
  <remove name="Session" />
  <remove name="PassportAuthentication" />
  <remove name="AnonymousIdentification" />
</httpModules>
```

Now for you case I continue on assemblies session, this is what I see on global web.config:

```
<compilation>
        <assemblies>
            <remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="mscorlib" />
            <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <add assembly="*" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </assemblies>
```

this as it is I copy/paste to my web.config and place `<clear />` on first line then I start remove the lines that I KNOW that my program is not use... and be careful to keep this line `<add assembly="*" />` and at the end, this says to add your library from your dll directory.

```
            <assemblies>
                <clear />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="mscorlib" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
....
                <add assembly="*" />
            </assemblies>
```

Making this and removing the one that you not use, by remove and see if your application is still working, you can limit a lot the assemblies that you use.

I make a simple test and by removing this line

```
<add assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

I count from 83 down to 79 only assemblies loaded this time. Why more than one minus ? because `WorkflowServices` loads some more by them self.

To remove something from configuration section, again on your web.config you do it as:

```
<configuration> 
  <configSections>
        <remove name="system.data.oracleclient"></remove>
...
```

Comment: `OracleClient` in not in locations described in answer. Default `machine.config` contains `<section name="system.data.oracleclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>`. Can this cause oracle client loading ? How to force .NET not to load it without manually changing machine.config in every customer server?

Comment: @Andrus Similar, on the configSection on your `web.config` add a line `<configSections><remove name="system.data.oracleclient"></remove>...` to remove it

Comment: This causes error `invalid child element 'remove'` . I updated question with my attempts to remove it

Comment: Oracle config is not defined anywhere. will presence of Oracle section definition in machine.config file cause System.Data.OracleClient assembly loading ?

Comment: @Andrus What I have type here I first test it, in my computer for some reason is not throw error, but its works. Now the oracle section definition is not cause any assembly loading unless you use on web.config this part.

Comment: I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094420/how-to-not-to-load-oracle-client-assembly

Answer (score 0):

My workstation at work has references to Oracle all throughout my machine.config.  I believe you're going to find your rogue references there.

`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`

Comment: Default `machine.config` contains only `<section name="system.data.oracleclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>`. Oracle client config section is not defined anywhere. Can this cause oracle client loading ? How to force .NET not to load it without manually changing machine.config in every customer server?